# How to convert a date 15-May-2019 in SQL to 2019/05/15 using PATINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, converters, patindex

I need to convert a date in SQL. The date as is `15-May-2019` and it should display as `2019/05/15`.

This is the code I have so far

```
CASE WHEN WHEN LEN(AgeGroup) > 1 THEN PATINDEX ('%[A-Z]%', date)
```

I'm not completely sure how to use `Patindex`. Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: The use of `patindex()` suggests that this is SQL Server, so I added the tag.

Comment: Store the correct type instead - `date`. Dates have no format, they're binary values. Once you have the correct type you can use `FORMAT`, eg `FORMAT(someDate,'YYYY/MM/DD')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code and you can refer the link for other formats.https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

```html
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,(cast('15-may-2019' as date)), 111)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend just converting to the `date` data type:

```
select try_convert(date, '15-May-2019')
```

If you want it with slashes, you can produce a string instead:

```
select replace(convert(varchar(10), try_convert(date, '15-May-2019'), 120), '-', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

`PATINDEX` is slightly overkilling.

Try:

```
SELECT FORMAT(
      TRY_PARSE('15-May-2019' AS DATE USING 'en-US')
, 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

- `TRY_PARSE` parses the string to DATE using `English` culture.
- `FORMAT` is to precisely control the output